# How to list all the browser catalogue data products in AWS Data-Exchange using API calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, sdk, aws-data-exchange

I want to fetch the data products that are present in the AWS Data-Exchange Browse Catalogue list. I would like to fetch those lists whose Pricing Plans category is free

Is there an SDK in AWS to list those data products?

Answer (score 0):

(I work for AWS Data Exchange)

While we [do have an API to enumerate and manage the products you own](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/welcome.html) and [a working sample of using that API](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dataexchange-api-samples/tree/master/providers/ruby/enumerate-data-products), we currently don't have an API available for enumerating all products in the catalogue, unfortunately.

What is your use-case, please?

Comment: My use case is to list the products that are available for free subscription under Data Exchange using the DataExchange API

Comment: @r123 I guess I'm asking for what (kind of) purpose or application, and for what kind of customer?